# Map Json to POJO class using Rest Template exchange method

Tags: json, spring, spring-boot

This is my POST request to an API

```
ResponseEntity<String> result = rt.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, httpEntity, String.class);
```

The response i am getting is below

```
{
    "headers": {
        "Cache-Control": [
            "no-store"
        ],
        "Content-Type": [
            "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
        ],
        "Date": [
            "Thu, 20 Jun 2019 12:50:08 GMT"
        ],
        "Pragma": [
            "no-cache"
        ],
        "Server": [
            "val"
        ],
        "X-Content-Type-Options": [
            "nosniff"
        ],
        "X-Frame-Options": [
            "DENY"
        ],
        "X-Xss-Protection": [
            "1; mode=block"
        ],
        "Content-Length": [
            "331"
        ]
    },
    "body": {
        "access_token": "token_value,
        "scope": "KYC",
        "token_type": "bearer",
        "expires_in": 49900,
        "jti": "jti_val"
    },
    "statusCode": "OK",
    "statusCodeValue": 200
}
```

I need to get extract
access_token,scope,token_type,statusCodeValue

So what should be structure of my POJO class to map the response ?Or how can i get the values from JSON for those fields ?

```
ResponseEntity<PojoClass> result = rt.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, httpEntity, PojoClass.class);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Body can get through the snippet posted above and status code can be retrieved using "response.getStatus()"

Answer (score 0):

**try this:updated**

```
 ResponseEntity<Response> response = rt.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, httpEntity, Response.class);
```

**Class definition:**

Body Class:

```
public class Body implements Serializable{
    private String access_token;
    private String scope;
    private String token_type;
    private long expires_in;
    private String jti;

    //standard getters and setters

}
```

Response class:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Response implements Serializable{
    private String statusCode;
    private int statusCodeValue;
    private Body body;

    //standard getters and setters

}
```

Now:
you should access your desired values using their respective getters method.
like:

```
String token=response.getBody.getAccessToken();
String statusCode= respnse.getStatusCode();
```

Comment: response.getBody.getAccessToken();  response.getBody is not able to access getAccessToken();

Comment: String token=response.getBody().getBody().getAccess_token();
//Null pointer exception
Your pseudo code is itself incorrect .You can't access token like this


String token=response.getBody.getAccessToken();

Comment: i think you are doing hit n trial method

Comment: @OracleMonkey, why do you think, my pseudo code is incorrect? what is wrong in this: `String token=response.getBody.getAccessToken();` ?
You must generate getters and setters for your class entities and use those getters to access a particular varible. It may vary by name as I used `getAccessToken` this. No, its not hit and trial, suggestion was made based on your code segment you provided.